# Regexp puzzle : encapsulated structures

Tags: c, regex, macros, preprocessor

So here I am trying to do something all programmers probably had to done as well one day.

I have all those nested macros in my code and I want to comment next to each #endif which #if it closes - if there is no comment yet. Can a regexp do that for me ? Until now * and + have been too greedy in Notepad++, even if I used the theoretically lazy version *? and +? ...

For example this

```
#if A

Code

#if B

Code

#if C

Code

#endif

Code

#endif /* B */

Code

#endif
```

Into this

```
#if A

Code

#if B

Code

#if C

Code

#endif /* C */

Code

#endif /* B */

Code

#endif /* A */
```

Comment: Regular expression can't handle nested structures. Even with backtracking extensions I'm not sure it would be possible.

Comment: Not possible in general, as this isn't a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). One way to proof it is that in the general case, you couldn't parse it with a finite number of states.

Comment: If you are using Notepad++, why didn't you tag it with Notepad++? NPP regex flavor is Boost, and it can handle recursion.

Comment: So, a regex isn't the solution, but it could be solved with a simple [tag:perl] script (or even some C code). -- @WiktorStribiżew interesting feature, although this isn't "regular" any more ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Perl, PCRE, Boost, Python PyPi regex, Ruby's Onigmo (former Oniguruma) - all support recursion.  .NET supports balanced construct that uses a stack for captures where you may push and pull the captured values from and onto the stack to track their count. No one really is interested if the expressions are regular, people need the result.

Comment: A Vim macro like this: `:set nowrapscan^M1GO?^#if^V^M3l"ay$%:s,endif.*$,endif /*^V^Ra */,^V^M%@b^[0"by$ddG@b`  Just yank this into a buffer and execute. ^V, ^M, ^R and ^[ are ctrl-*that character*

Comment: using perl: `my @m; while (<STDIN>){ if (/^#if(?:def)?\s(.*)$/) { push @m, $1; print; } elsif (/^(#endif)\s?(.*)$/) { my $x = pop @m; print "$1 /* $x */\n"; } else { print; } }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this be done with a single regular expression? Hell no!

Can this be done in Notepad++ using *only* regular expressions? **HELL YEAH**!!!

1. Turn OFF `. matches newline`.
2. Replace all `\r\n` with `\n`. This makes the regular expressions much simpler on Windows. You can change them back later if you want.
3. Clear all existing `#endif` markings by replacing `^#endif.*` with `#endif`.
4. We need to focus on only `#if...` and `#endif` lines, so we ignore all the others by replacing `^(?!#(if|endif)).*` with `;$0`. So `;` is our 'ignore' marker.
5. Next, we repeatedly alter `#if` - `#endif` pairs that only have ignored lines between them.
    So, repeatedly 'Replace All' 
   `^#if(.+)\n((;.*\n)*)#endif`
   with
   `;#if$1\n$2;#endif /* $1 */`. 
   This applies the comment to all `#if` -
   `#endifs` at the lowest nesting level, and then marks them with `;`, so the next time you click 'Replace All', they are ignored.
6. When you are done, remove the ignore markers by replacing `^;(.+?\n)` with `$1`.

VOILA!

Comment: Ah ! Hadn't thought about repeatedly using find/replace, modifying stuff along the way. This way of thinking in general will definitely be useful in the future !